# Disable SELECT before INSERT/UPDATE in multi-module java application

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, multi-module

I have an entity class defined as below in a common module.

```
@Entity(name="TABLE_NAME")
class TableName{
....
}
```

Now I have two modules `module1` and `module2` where module1 `INSERT`s row of data and `module2` does an UPDATE on data. We are using `saveEntity()` which is doing a select before INSERT/UPDATE. This table being large table is taking some time to do insert/update and occupying sessions as well. @Entity class is accessed from both module1 and module2 as a dependency. My question is

1. how can I disable select before INSERT in module1?
2. How can I disable select before UPDATE in module2?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring-data-jpa, having JPA repositories can help instead, something like

`@Repository public interface TableNameRepository extends JpaRepository<TableName, DataTypeOfIdInTheEntityClass> {}`

and then call the method
`TableNameRepository.save(entityObject)`

Comment: My understanding is that save() will call SELECT to know if it's a new ID or not. Then it will make a decision to INSERT if it's a new key else an update. I see two roundtrips here. I am trying to avoid this.

Comment: One option I am thinking is to implement Persistable<ID> on entity and override isNew() to true. But in module2 isNew() should be overriden to false. That's where I have a dilema on implementation.

Comment: On a slightly different note, just curious, assuming that there can be multiple parallel calls to the save method in the module, isn't the safeguard of selecting the latest snapshot of entity before merging the changes a good thing ?

Comment: My application always tries to save the latest snapshot and there are no subsequent save/update in module for that entity in a module. When I hit save() in a module, that entity being saved is saved to DB and not used again in the module.